# Assessing the condition and wear on camshaft

Tags: camshaft

Does this lobe looks worn? I’m trying to assess the condition of the camshaft.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The lobe looks fine to me, unless the dots in the second picture are pits - but I think they are just dust and/or reflections.

If I was rebuilding and intended to reuse the camshaft, I would mirror polish on a rouge wheel.  That takes some expertise; might be better left to a cam professional with the right equipment and knowledge.

Could use a hot dip to get rid of the coking and crud near the bearing caps.  You'll need to pull the valve cover to assess the total condition of the cam - not just the one lobe you can see through the oil filler neck.  It would be wise to remove a cradle cap or two to see the bearing surfaces as well.

Otherwise, I don't see much cause for concern, at least on that one lobe.

Comment: Here’s a follow up with the VC removed, this engine is supposed to have 35,000 miles. isn’t the wear extremely excessive? was it starving for oil? https://youtu.be/6zpVR7R3npM